# GetTransform().R.col2.Copy in Xcode

Tags: javascript, xcode, cocoa, box2d

Hi i am making game in Xcode from below link, which is made in JS

http://www.codekites.com/make-racing-car-box2d-javascript/

Now i am stucked for GetTransform().R.col2.Copy (line 332 in undate_car function) conversion, which gets the direction of Car.

Now when i saw in Xcode, its giving me upto GetTransform() but there is no "R". There is only p (of type b2Vec2) and q (of type b2Rot).

Please help me, how to get direction from Body to update?

Comment: Xcode supports JavaScript? Maybe using a dedicated JS IDE like Eclipse or WebStorm would be a better choice?

Comment: No Xcode doesn't support JS if using Box2D... but Basically I am converting Javascript code into Objective C from self. So i want help in this.

Comment: I didn't get that from your question - you might want to rework it so people understand what it is you're actually trying to do.

Comment: You need to find out what `R` is in the original; then you'll know which of the other two members, or what other solution, is the replacement. (As a blind guess: Perhaps `R` stands for Rotation?)

Comment: Thanks Peter, but still no hope for it. :(

Answer (score 0):

Got the help from one blog.
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/20628

Main points are as follows:

- b2Mat22 changed to b2Rot
- b2PolygonShape->SetAsEdge() was removed; instead use b2EdgeShape->Set()
- b2World(gravity) instead of b2World(gravity, doSleep); doSleep is true by default; can be changed using SetAllowSleeping
- b2LineJoint and b2LineJointDef was removed; not sure what you can use instead, please if anyone knows ..?
- b2Transform changed a bit: instead of .position use .p, and similar
- **.R -> .q**, **.R.col1 -> .q.GetXAxis()** and **.R.col2 became .q.GetYAxis()**